# Node, Windows 10 and Bash interaction. Pipe doesn't work

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, cygwin, git-bash

Note that the following command line hangs under bash running almost any version of node that I've tried (can you give me one where it works?) or my Windows 10 system is hosed.  It does work under command prompt.

```
$ yes | xargs node fillbuffer.js | tee xx
0
0


$ cat fillbuffer.js
console.log(0);
```

I've installed a new bash and bash utilities under cygwin and git bash (should I try msys?).

Note that this works:

```
$ yes | xargs sh fill.sh | tee xx
0
0
.
.
.

$ cat fill.sh
echo 0
```

Comment: I'm expecting the output to be the same as the fill.sh example that does work

Comment: Don't forget to type CTRL-C to interrupt the processes if you are newbie.  And remove the excess xx file this creates.

Comment: `node` is NOT a cygwin program so he could require a CRLF or be unable to work with  cygwin pipe.

Comment: @matzeri, I think console.log adds the CRLF

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution to my problem.  It may not solve all node problems, because in many cases, you don't want to exit.  Here's the solution:

fillbuffer.js:

```
console.log(0);
process.exit();
```